# Why does the swiper breakpoints prop not work in vue.js?

Tags: vue.js, responsive-design, swiper.js

I use Swiper Element with breakpoints prop in a vue 2 project. I wish it shows 1 column at mobile while shows 4 columns by the window width >= 1024px. But it shows 1 column at both mobile and pc terminal. Please someone helps me to fix it. Thanks a lot!
The template code:

```
<swiper-container
    init="false"
    class="swiper-instruction"
  >
    <swiper-slide
      v-for="(item, index) in data.resources"
      :key="item.resourceId"
    >
      <div
        class="cursor-pointer card-wrap"
        @click="toDetail(item)"
      >
        <ImageCard
          class="height-image xl:h-52 lg:h-44 sm:h-32"
          :src="item.cover"
          :text="item.resourceType=='scenicspots' ? item.resourceName : null"
          :textType="item.resourceType=='scenicspots' ? 'shade' : ''"
          is-instruction
          :country="item.countryName"
          :slogan="item.resourceName"
        />
      </div>
    </swiper-slide>
  </swiper-container>
```

The script code:

```
mounted() {
  this.initializeSwiperIns();
},
methods: {
  initializeSwiperIns(){
  const swiperEl = document.querySelector('swiper-container.swiper-instruction');

  const params = {
    // array with CSS styles
    injectStyles: [
      `
      .swiper {
        overflow: visible;
        --swiper-navigation-size: 0;
      }
      .swiper-horizontal > .swiper-pagination-bullets,
      .swiper-pagination-bullets.swiper-pagination-horizontal {
        bottom: -54px;
        width: auto;
      }
      .swiper-pagination-bullet-active {
        background-color: rgb(241, 90, 34);
        width: 24px;
        border-radius: 4px;
      }
      `,
    ],
    slidesPerView: 1,
    spaceBetween: 15,
    breakpoints: {
      1024: {
        slidesPerView: 4,
        spaceBetween: 30,
      },
    },
    pagination: {
      clickable: true,
    },
    navigation: 'true',
    loop: false,
  };

  Object.assign(swiperEl, params);
  swiperEl.initialize();
  },
}
```